# How to expire a particular row in SQL Server once a date is reached?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008-express

It may be very simple scenario for experienced developers, but as a beginner I have been hanging around this for a long time. I am creating a website in asp.net where  a user can purchase a packages. These packages have some expiry date associated with them (e.g. 2 months after purchase, 6 months, etc.).

The problem is how to expire each package exactly at the same date and time that i have calculated on the basis of purchase date. How to do this thing?

I am using SQL Server express edition 2008 and asp.net 4.0 .

Comment: What do you mean by "expire"?  Delete from the database?  Mark a field as "expired"?

Comment: @WaqarJanjua It's not a trigger if it's after n months.

Comment: @Meryovi I guess may be he wants to delete after sometime automatically.

Comment: @WaqarJanjua I believe that would be a job, not a trigger.

Comment: I just want to show the user that his purchased package is now expired, that can be done by updating the status as expired. but when should i fire this update query? that's the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends a bit on what you mean by expire - do you want to delete the data, flag the record, or just hide the data from the user's screen.

Either way, you need to add the expiry date as a column to your table (?packages), and save the calculated expiry date into this column.

You then have options such as :

- Run a job to delete / expire the record once it has expired, i.e. `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is > ExpiryDate` (SQL Express doesn't have SQL Agent, so you would need to e.g. write a windows service, or hook into Windows Task Scheduler to do this).
- Or, change your application to 'check' the value of the ExpiryDate (e.g. `DateTime.Now >= ExpiryDate`), and then lock the user out / hide the package from the UI.

Comment: May be windows service can work in this case. I will try this option first.

Answer (score 13):

Rather than deleting the records, you could put a `WHERE` clause in place which would exclude the records based on their expiry date:

```
SELECT PackageName
FROM Package
WHERE ExpiryDate>GETDATE()
```

However if you still wish to remove them from the database, you could put a [SQL Job](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191439.aspx) in place which is ran every day/hour etc which would delete records which have expired:

```
DELETE FROM Package
WHERE ExpiryDate<GETDATE()
```